# How do I save these outputs into any sort of text file or pdf

Tags: r, pdf, matrix, export

I want to save this 4 outputs in any form

They are all matrices and Id also like to get them in a certain order too, I tried pdf() but that didn't work

```
sampleMean <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sampleMean),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sampleMean

sampleVar <-lapply(lyst, var)
sampleVar <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(sampleVar),nrow = 7, ncol = 7, byrow = T))
sampleVar

pdf(file = "result3.pdf",width = 40, height = 30)
theoretical_mean
sampleMean

theoretical_var
sampleVar
dev.off()
```

Comment: You can use the command `saveRDS()`. See how it works with `?saveRDS`.

Comment: The kable() function in knitr is a very simple table generator, if you want to compile a pdf ,or html look for rmarkdown knitr pandoc, etc

Comment: @Taufi I tried using saveRDS but is there a way where I can save it to a text file where I can see the output right there. saveRDS doesn't actually let me see the output, it opens up R and prompts me to use readRDS

Comment: @user12197328 I answered properly, hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As a response to your question in the comments, here is a way that let's you see the output directly in a text file.

Let

```
A = data.frame(A = c("Hi", "you", "there"), B = c("How", "are", "you?"))
```

Then use the `kable`-command from the `knitr`package and the base function `capture.output` to save the data.frame to your disk like so

```
capture.output(knitr::kable(A), file = "test.txt")
```

The output in the text file is

```
|A     |B    |
|:-----|:----|
|Hi    |How  |
|you   |are  |
|there |you? |
```

You can make better looking tables in R easily. Search for `kableExtra`.

Let me know if this helps.